# Can you please Explain the output and point out mistake

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, memset

```
char FramebufferUpdateRequest[11];
uint16_t val;
memset(FramebufferUpdateRequest, 0, 10);
FramebufferUpdateRequest[0] = 3;
FramebufferUpdateRequest[1] = 1;
val = 3;
memcpy(FramebufferUpdateRequest+6, &val, 2);
val = 2;
memcpy(FramebufferUpdateRequest+8, &val, 2);
FramebufferUpdateRequest[10]='\0';
printf("framerequest :: %c  %s\n", FramebufferUpdateRequest[1], FramebufferUpdateRequest);
```

output of this printf is Blank i.e "framerequest ::    ".Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

compiled in gcc 4.1.2

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?  You're trying to print non-printing characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to write:

```
memset(FramebufferUpdateRequest, 0, 10);
FramebufferUpdateRequest[0] = '3'; //notice the difference
FramebufferUpdateRequest[1] = '1'; //notice the difference
val = '3';  //or var = ('3' << 1 | '3') if you want both bytes to have '3'
memcpy(FramebufferUpdateRequest+6, &val, 2);
val = '2';  //or var = ('2' << 1 | '2') if you want both bytes to have '2'
```

Know the difference between `'1'` and `1`:

```
   cout << (int) ('1') << endl;
   cout << (int) (1) << endl;
```

Output: ( http://www.ideone.com/z3spn )

```
49
1
```

Explanation: `'1'` is  a [character literal](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc02ccon.htm), whose ascii value is `49`, whereas `1` is an integer.

Comment: thanks but say val = '3'; 
memcpy(FramebufferUpdateRequest+6, &val, 2); --> char is only 8 bit and val is 16 bit.. how this memcpy will work. Also if i take input of val from stdin then...

Comment: @honeybadger: Good question. I appreciate it. Since var is 2-byte, so only one byte of it will contain `'3'` and the other byte will be `0`. If you want to make both byte `'3'`, then you can do this : `var = ('3' << 1 | '3');` .

Comment: so if say i took input val from stdin, and then do : char value = val; and memcpy(FramebufferUpdateRequest+6, &value, 2); It is good coz memcpy will put 0 in other 8 bit. right?

Comment: @honeybadger: If you want both bytes to have same value, then you should use `memset` instead of `memcpy`. And this is how you should do use it : `char input; cin >> input; memset(FramebufferUpdateRequest+6, input, 2);`. ....... see [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) .

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning unprintable characters to `FramebufferUpdateRequest`.

You will need to somehow convert it either to integers (ie. use a loop and `%d`) or printable characters (for example, add `'A'` to every element).

The basic set of printable characters is shown [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).